# Name of this Android UI component (img)

Tags: android

I would ask what is name of this UI component:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/i6a0bdrjh/]

I need a make something like this in my app., so I will very happy if you answer me :)

Comment: ... isn't it an **expanded** `Spinner`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called as Spinners in android.... here is a link for a tutorial that will help u creating one.

[Tutorial Link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/)

You can find the official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

Comment: Please mark this answer as Solved if it satisfied your query so that it can help others.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html).

> Spinners provide a quick way to select one value from a set. In the default state, a spinner shows its currently selected value. Touching the spinner displays a dropdown menu with all other available values, from which the user can select a new one.

(cf [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html))